# How to calculate the frequency of dictionary elements and remove duplicate dictionary elements in python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, the elements in the list is a dict type.

For example,

```
da_list = [
    {'Surface':'APPLE','BaseForm':'apple','PN':0.5},
    {'Surface':'BANANA','BaseForm':'banana','PN':0.4},
    {'Surface':'ORANGE','BaseForm':'orange','PN':-0.1},
    {'Surface':'APPLE','BaseForm':'apple','PN':0.5},
    {'Surface':'BANANA','BaseForm':'banana','PN':0.4} 
]
```

I want to define a new list with the name db_list.
The db_list stores dict element likes this:

```
db_list = [
    {'Surface':'APPLE','BaseForm':'apple','PN':0.5,'Frequency':2},
    {'Surface':'BANANA','BaseForm':'banana','PN':0.4,'Frequency':2},
    {'Surface':'ORANGE','BaseForm':'orange','PN':-0.1,'Frequency':1} 
]
```

The `db_list` removes the duplicate elements in `da_list`, and adds the frequency of each dictionary.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also user `Counter` together with `list comprehension`

```
from collections import Counter
>>> [dict(k + (('frequency', v),)) for k,v in Counter(tuple(k.items()) for k in da_list).items()]

[{'Surface': 'APPLE', 'BaseForm': 'apple', 'PN': 0.5, 'frequency': 2},
 {'Surface': 'BANANA', 'BaseForm': 'banana', 'PN': 0.4, 'frequency': 2},
 {'Surface': 'ORANGE', 'BaseForm': 'orange', 'PN': -0.1, 'frequency': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
da_list = [{'Surface':'APPLE','BaseForm':'apple','PN':0.5}, {'Surface':'BANANA','BaseForm':'banana','PN':0.4}, {'Surface':'ORANGE','BaseForm':'orange','PN':-0.1}, {'Surface':'APPLE','BaseForm':'apple','PN':0.5}, {'Surface':'BANANA','BaseForm':'banana','PN':0.4}]
new_result = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(da_list, key=lambda x:x['Surface']), key=lambda x:x['Surface'])]
final_result = [{**i[0], 'Frequency':len(i)} for i in new_result]
```

Output:

```
[{'Surface': 'APPLE', 'BaseForm': 'apple', 'PN': 0.5, 'Frequency': 2}, {'Surface': 'BANANA', 'BaseForm': 'banana', 'PN': 0.4, 'Frequency': 2}, {'Surface': 'ORANGE', 'BaseForm': 'orange', 'PN': -0.1, 'Frequency': 1}]
```

Comment: Excuse me, what does `**i[0]` mean here? Any documentation for that?

Comment: @ytu `**` is dictionary unpacking a feature in `python 3.x`. You may be familiar with `**kwargs` as a parameter in a function signature to accept a variable number of parameter assignments, however, the syntax can also be used to "flatten" or "imbed" dictionaries in one another. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/